# "Famigerato": quando ha assunto una valenza negativa?

Tags: etymology

Definizione del termine "famigerato":

`famigerato agg. [dal lat. famigeratus, part. pass. di famigerare «render famoso», comp. di fama «fama» e tema di gerĕre «portare»].`

L'etimologia non ha certo un valore negativo (portare fama). Eppure il termine si utilizza esclusivamente per indicare qualcosa di "tristemente noto", o comunque dando una valenza ironica a qualcosa di famoso per qualcosa di spiacevole.

Qualcuno sa quando nel tempo, e come si è imposta tale valenza negativa, in qualche modo contrapposta a quella puramente etimologica?

Comment: Questa è una domanda realmente interessante, forse la più interessante finora posta on IL, +1.

Comment: non so rispondere, ma immagino che questo sia successo attraverso un meccanismo simile a quello tuttora in atto per _affatto_

Comment: in una ricerca assolutamente non metodica su google books ho trovato questa voce del 1825, dove curiopsamente sembra che al tempo  l'accezione negativa ci fosse anche per "rinomato"   http://books.google.it/books?id=zfAsAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22famigerato%22&pg=PA89#v=onepage&q=%22famigerato%22&f=false ...  attendo anch'io lumi da qualcuno più competente!

Comment: @laika, secondo me sbagli, e lo fai perché leggi quel testo con l'attuale accezione di _famigerato_ in mente

Comment: @WalterTross: occhio, con “affatto” è successa una cosa diversa dalla determinazione della *vox media* (vedi la mia risposta qui sotto): si sta solo perdendo il “non”, o altra particella negativa, che viene per così dire assorbita in “affatto”, come in passato era già successo per esempio con “mica” (in origine “briciola”, “cosa piccolissima”: non ho mica voglia di... = non ho neppure una voglia minuscola di...). Analogamente per “pas” in francese.

Comment: @DaG: l'assorbimento del _non_ è proprio dovuto alla cristallizzazione di _affatto_ all'interno di un certo tipo di frasi, che è appunto analogo all'utilizzo di _famigerato_ in un certo tipo di frasi

Comment: @WalterTross: Già, può essere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Attenzione, non è che il senso negativo sia proprio contrapposto a quello etimologico.
In latino *fama* era una *vox media*, non specificamente positiva né negativa: indicava in origine una notizia, una voce, e di lì la notorietà che derivava dal fatto che si parlasse di qualcuno o qualcosa. Altri esempi di *voces mediae* sono *fortuna* in latino (un caso, una sorte generica, non necessariamente positiva) e “successo” in italiano antico (che indica un qualunque esito di un'azione).
Nel corso del tempo una *vox media* tende a cristallizzarsi con l'uso, a essere codificata dal senso generico verso una delle accezioni “qualitative” possibili.

(Lo so, non è una risposta specifica su “famigerato”, ma spero possa essere d'aiuto.)

Comment: Grazie per il contributo, proprio per questo infatti avevo scritto "in qualche modo contrapposta", in effetti non è in netta contrapposizione. Questo comunque non aiuta a capire come e quando l'accezione negativa sia per l'appunto cristallizzata con l'uso, ma è comunque una integrazione utile, grazie

Comment: @Lorenzo, la risposta di *wing* è comunque attendibile, anche se non ha ancora voti; considera che siamo rimasti in pochi qui, però.

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis: Quando dici “siamo rimasti in pochi qui” ti riferisci ai frequentatori di Italian.SE? Siamo più di 450, e se ne aggiungono via via (una trentina solo nelle ultime due settimane: http://italian.stackexchange.com/users?tab=NewUsers&sort=creationdate) Di che stai parlando?

Comment: @DaG, non pensavo fossimo 450! Però there is a lack of questions, though.

Comment: La Crusca ha recentemente espresso un parere a riguardo: http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/valore-famigerato

Answer (score 2):

Dipende da come viene posta l'affermazione.
Se l'interlocutore è a conoscenza dei fatti accaduti, ad esempio se si tratta di un evento "buffo", è implicito che stai dando un taglio ironico alla frase.

Ecco un banale esempio:

"Ti ricordi il famigerato forzuto del paese?"

(magari riferendosi ad un fatto di cronaca del paese noto a tutti e in questo caso tutti sanno che si sta alludendo ad una persona per nulla forzuta ma che si spacciava per tale)

Stesso discorso se ci si riferisce ad un evento triste, positivo etc.

Forse, dato il suono della parola stessa che è meno "melodiosa" di "famoso", si usa nella maggior parte dei casi in contesti negativi.. (ma è una mia personale opinione).

UPDATE: Attira di più "il famigerato assassino di Londra" o "il famoso assassino di Londra"?

http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/famigerato/

Answer (score 0):

Credo che abbia assunto connotati negativi nell'epoca storica del brigantaggio, dove alcuni criminali diventavano noti in vaste aree del territorio per la loro latitanza

Comment: Fonte? (“Credo che” non è il massimo dell'utilità.)

Comment: Fonte un prof di latino che una volta ha dato questa spiegazione, però non posso confermare al 100%, da qui il mio "credo che".

Comment: @DaG, credo di aver letto questa cosa nel libro di Pino Aprile, 'Terroni'; but I'm not able to find that fragment  anymore, though.